# Could not load type 'System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection' from assembly 'System.Drawing'

Tags: c#, xunit, .net-4.8

I need create special fork of library TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp for my Net framework 4.8 web application. In this case I creating library without GUI, this will special PDF creator. Job done and all working fine with test from windows console application, I have received all needed result of my library with special PDF creator.

As reference my library used

```
HtmlRenderer.dll
HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.dll
PdfSharp.dll
PdfSharp.Charting.dll
System.Drawing.Common.dll
Microsoft.VisualBasic
System
System.Data
System.Deployment 
System.Drawing
System.Windows.Forms
System.Xml
System.Core
System.Xml.Linq
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
System.Net.Http
```

Then I try to test my library with xUnit test project. I expect the same result as perform my library by simple console application, but no.

I receive error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.Adapters.PdfSharpAdapter' threw an exception.
---- System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection' from assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

I check my System.Drawing library and it really contains class InstalledFontCollection

```
#region Assembly System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\System.Drawing.dll
// Decompiled with ICSharpCode.Decompiler 7.1.0.6543
#endregion
namespace System.Drawing.Text
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Represents the fonts installed on the system. This class cannot be inherited.
    public sealed class InstalledFontCollection : FontCollection
    {
        ...
```

Than I look to code that create error, this is absolutely ordinary code, also it working fine when I test my library with console application.

[image: InstalledFontCollection]

It's looks as xUnit test project block System.Drawing.dll library, or... I don't understand why I can not test my library.

Comment: Is your xUnit Test Project  a .Net Core project while your application is a .Net 4.8 project?

Comment: Get rid of System.Drawing.Common, the System.Drawing reference is enough.

Comment: @quaabaam, yes, you are right, it's a my mistake. Please add you comment as solution

Comment: @Alex16 My comment isn't really an answer and is more of a clue. I think it would be better if you posted exactly what you did to fix the issue. If your answer post makes sense then I'll upvote it. :)

Answer (score 1):

With @quaabaam help I found the issue. Any test projects need all external references for class we testing for. And now xUnit has only embedded NET CORE template for VS2022. And Issue was the System.Drawing for .NET Framework and System.Drawing for .NET Core really has different functions.

So, my solution is going from xUnit to MS UtitTest because MS Unit test still exist in .NET Framework.

In this case (MS Test with .NET Framework) I perform my testing class successfully (in line 29) and receive result I expected (special PDF document in browser).

[image: successful test]